# How Do I Change the Scope of a Designer-Created WPF User Control from Public to Friend in VB.Net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net. I have a WPF User Control called "NavigationPanel" which I created with the Designer. By default, its scope is Public. When I change its scope to Friend in the file NavigationPanel.xaml.vb, I recieve the following error:

> Specified access 'Public' for
>   'NavigationPanel' does not match the
>   access 'Friend' specified on one of
>   its other partial types.

The error applies to a Designer-generated file called NavigationPanel.g.vb. It declares NavigationPanel with the line:

```
Partial Public Class NavigationPanel
```

If I manually change "Public" to "Friend" on that line, or if I delete the file, the Designer keeps recreating it with "Public", and raising the error. I can't figure out why the Designer thinks it is appropriate to declare the class with the scope "Public", and I can't figure out how to convince the Designer to use "Friend" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you can do is make it public or not public since the corresponding API in xaml is limited to that (public by default ... non public if you request it) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754029.aspx
Update : yes it is possible. Read comment by T.C.

Comment: Thank you, Basarat Ali. The page you referred me to contains the answer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754029.aspx). That answer is: To change the scope of a user control to Friend, use x:ClassModifier="Friend" in the xaml file. (In C#, the equivalent is x:ClassModifier="internal".)